# Why isn't my position: sticky element sticking in my flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position

I have a container that is set to display: flex. My child element is set to position: sticky with a top set, but the element is not sticking at all, it just continues with the flow of the page. I've tried to set the align-items property to no avail.

What else am I missing to make this stick? It's basically just sticking the sidebar to the top of its column.

```css
.single-casestudy .casestudy-content {
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.row {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -1rem;
    margin-left: -1rem;
}
.single-casestudy .results {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    color: #333f48;
    line-height: 1.349;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    align-self: flex-start;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 62em)
.col-md-4 {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.333%;
    flex-basis: 33.333%;
    max-width: 33.333%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 62em)
.col-md-4 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="row casestudy-content">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 results">
    content here
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 thecontent">
     more content here
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your position sticky is working just fine. The demo below shows the first flex-item positioned as sticky, and a lot of content is placed in the second flex-item. Because first flex-item (.results) is positioned to stick at the top of the flex-box, when the user scrolls, the content in .results sticks, but the content in .thecontent scrolls. Once the user scrolls past the end of flex-box, the sticky content will then go off the page because it is stuck to the top of the flex-box.

I changed the col widths of the flex-items and added a filler at the end of the page content for better demonstration purposes in the snippet.

```css
.filler {
  height: 1000px;
}

.single-casestudy .casestudy-content {
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.row {
  /*  box-sizing: border-box; */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  margin-right: -1rem;
  margin-left: -1rem;
}

.single-casestudy .results {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  color: #333f48;
  line-height: 1.349;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  background-color: coral;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 62em) .col-md-4 {
  -ms-flex-preferred-size: 33.333%;
  flex-basis: 33.333%;
  max-width: 33.333%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 62em) .col-md-4 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row single-casestudy">
  <div class="col-6 results">
    Sticky content here
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 thecontent">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus
    vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis
    imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
    elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula,
    facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae
    dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla
    et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis
    in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis.
    Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque
    enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit
    risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
    imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed
    ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus
    gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum,
    nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent
    convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla
    congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque
    enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit
    risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar
    nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue
    eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum
    dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio,
    vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus
    interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum.
    Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis
    dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc
    sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta.
    Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices
    nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper
    ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum
    augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet
    sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="filler"></div>
```

Comment: The element I want to stick continues to scroll with the page, regardless of the length of the content next to it. It does not work like your example.

Comment: Oh, something else I changed (because it didn't make sense in your code) was the class for the flex container that uses .casestudy-content. I changed this class to single-casestudy, since this is what is referenced in your CSS

Comment: If the classes aren't the issue, then there must be something else in your environment, that's not included in your post, that's interfering with it. I assumed that you are using Bootstrap because of the row and col classes - What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: We're not using bootstrap, but rather FlexBox grid.  I do agree that likely something else is interfering.